# If $\Phi$ is a flow on $\mathbb{R}$, show $\Phi(t,x)$ is monotone in $t$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $\Phi$ is a flow on $\mathbb{R}$, show $\Phi(t,x)$ is monotone in $t$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

There must be some $k,\delta >0$  such that $\Phi_{k}(x)=\Phi_{k+\delta}(x)$. Does this imply $\Phi_{\delta}=$ Id? Is this a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is hinting at the fact that non-monotonicity somehow contradicts Existence and Uniqueness.

Suppose that $\phi(t,x)$ is the flow for the ODE $\dot{x} = f(x)$.  Assume there is a time $t_0$ and an initial value $x_0$ such that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(t_0,x_0) = 0$, but the flow at this IC is non-constant in time (We will discuss the constant case in a moment).  Since $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(t,x) = f(\phi(t,x))$ we get that $f(\phi(t_0,x_0))=0$.  This means that the value $z_0 = \phi(t_0,x_0)$ is a constant solution to $\dot{x}=f(x)$.  However, Existence and Uniqueness implies then tells us we must have $\phi(t,x_0)=z_0$ for all $t$.  This contradicts our assumption that $\phi$ was non-constant.  So then for a non-constant flow we must have either $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} >0$ or $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} <0$ for all $t$.  Hence, the flow is monotonic in $t$.  What about the constant case?  Generally I tend to treat constant solutions as trivially monotonic, but that really depends on whether you have defined monotonicity strictly or not.